# unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am trying to implement a vote up button so that users can vote up a post. Something like a like feature.  To do that I use an IB action in the cell view controller like below

```
@IBAction func vote(sender: AnyObject) {

    if (parseObject != nil) {
        if var votes:Int? = parseObject!.objectForKey("votes") as? Int {
            votes!++

            parseObject!.setObject(votes!, forKey: "votes")
            parseObject!.saveInBackgroundWithTarget(nil, selector: nil)

            votesLabel?.text = "\(votes!) votes"
}
```

Then I put the below code in the collection view controller if nothing is in the column, the label will show 0.

```
     if var votes:Int? = parseObject!.objectForKey("votes") as? Int {
        if votes == nil{
            votes = 0}
        cell.votesLabel?.text = "\(votes!) votes" 
    }
    return cell
}
```

I have no errors in my code, however as soon as I build the app it says unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value pointing to the highlighted code. Is my way of implementing this wrong? Thank you.

Comment: It seems that `parseObject` is nil at that point

Comment: Thank you.  Very confused is it because of this code `if votes == nil{` However I need this code because if there isn't anything in votes it needs to show 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of forced unwrapping, you can try optional chaining. So the whole expression would return `nil` instead of throwing error.

`if var votes:Int? = parseObject?.objectForKey("votes") as? Int {`

**EDIT**

Its also a better practice to let Swift infer the type of variable, so:

`if var votes = parseObject?.objectForKey("votes") as? Int {`

Comment: Thank you that did it but now it only shows 0 and does not count up the votes even though I am tapping the vote button(Unbutton). It looks like it is not checking with parse since all post becomes 0

Comment: I think that the other problem is unrelated to this problem, and I suggest you to ask another question specifying the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try Below Code:

```
@IBAction func vote(sender: AnyObject) {
if (parseObject != nil)
{
     if let votes = parseObject!.objectForKey("votes") as? Int {
         parseObject!.setObject(votes + 1, forKey: "votes")
         parseObject!.saveInBackgroundWithTarget(nil, selector: nil)
         votesLabel?.text = "\(votes + 1) votes"
     }
     else
     {
         parseObject!.setObject(1, forKey: "votes")
         parseObject!.saveInBackgroundWithTarget(nil, selector: nil)
         votesLabel?.text = "1 votes"
     }
}
```

In collection view controller

```
if (parseObject != nil)
{

   if let votes = parseObject!.objectForKey("votes") as? Int {
       cell.votesLabel?.text = "\(votes) votes"
   }
   else
   {
       cell.votesLabel?.text = "0 votes"
   }
}
return cell
```

Comment: Hello Thank you for the comment I get an error for using cell saying use of unresolved identifier cell. This code is in the cell view controller.

Comment: Hello I still get no response.. It does not add votes in the label and remains 0. I also put a printin under the 6th line and can't see any thing printed

Comment: Yes this is what I tried last time... and got a nexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value. If I change it to a ? then it works but it doesn't retrieve the information from parse

Comment: @Satsuki then you have to add just one more condition in collection view controller. I will update answer.

Comment: Thank you for all the codes, using the above code it looks a lot worse. The labels won't change to anything. It just shows labels.Votes is a column in the post class.

Comment: @Satsuki I have update answer again. added `else` condition into `vote` function for very first time you click button it will create object for `votes` and set its value to `1`. and don't forgot to reload your collection view controller.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84553/discussion-between-satsuki-and-idhaval).

Comment: I still have problems the vote does not go up in parse instead creates a new object if I use this code in your answer.